# Repositories for older PHP versions and Apache modules

Tags: apt, apache2, php, repository, mongodb

Because of the pending loss of CentOS we are moving to a new operating system.  We have an application that REQUIRES php 7.0.33. After a few tries with other Operating systems, I was able to load the version we need on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I'm new to Ubuntu - I've worked for a few years now of Redhat and CentOS 7.

I have been unable to install all the php-modules from the CentOS webserver. Does anyone here know a way to search Ubuntu repositories and find the software I need to install: PHP modules that will work on the 7.0.33 PHP version - such as `mongodb`, `mysqli`, `mysqlnd` etc?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu with php 7.0  The oldest you can get is 7.4 The BETTER option is to fix your software.

Comment: I know! Right?!  That's what I said - but I'm going to have to show them there isn't a way for this to work.  IF I can find the rpm's for the php modules (mongodb etc.) will it even work in Ubuntu 22.03?

Comment: No, you need DEBs not RPM. Alien can convert rpm's to deb but that is more miss than hit ;) All the DEB's are in an archive   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/ but this gets cleared for EOL (but a bit later then that OS going EOL) and this does NOT cover 3rd party modules/packages. Doing this by hand is LESS difficult than fixing your software (and that fix is also better in the long run when 7.4 gets axxed  ;))

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use older PHP versions and modules, try `ppa:ondrej/php` repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

After that, you will be able to install PHP 7.0 and the modules you want. Package `php7.0-mysql` installs both `mysqlnd` and `mysqli`:

```
sudo apt install php7.0

sudo apt install php7.0-mongodb
sudo apt install php7.0-mysql
```